# Spring could not autowire field error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am getting below error for my spring based dynamic web project.I am new to spring and I am no sure why the below error is there -

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.persistent.eap.dao.UserRegistrationDetailsDao com.persistent.eap.service.impl.UserRegistrationServiceImpl.userRegistrationDetailsDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRegistrationDetailsDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0
```

below is the trace -

```
HTTP Status 500 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)


root cause 

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userRegistrationController' defined in file [D:\javawp\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\eapPortal\WEB-INF\classes\com\persistent\eap\controllers\UserRegistrationController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.persistent.eap.service.intfc.UserRegistrationService]: : Error creating bean with name 'userRegistrationService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.persistent.eap.dao.UserRegistrationDetailsDao com.persistent.eap.service.impl.UserRegistrationServiceImpl.userRegistrationDetailsDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRegistrationDetailsDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRegistrationService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.persistent.eap.dao.UserRegistrationDetailsDao com.persistent.eap.service.impl.UserRegistrationServiceImpl.userRegistrationDetailsDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRegistrationDetailsDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
 javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)


root cause 

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userRegistrationController' defined in file [D:\javawp\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\eapPortal\WEB-INF\classes\com\persistent\eap\controllers\UserRegistrationController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.persistent.eap.service.intfc.UserRegistrationService]: : Error creating bean with name 'userRegistrationService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.persistent.eap.dao.UserRegistrationDetailsDao com.persistent.eap.service.impl.UserRegistrationServiceImpl.userRegistrationDetailsDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRegistrationDetailsDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRegistrationService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.persistent.eap.dao.UserRegistrationDetailsDao com.persistent.eap.service.impl.UserRegistrationServiceImpl.userRegistrationDetailsDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRegistrationDetailsDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:730)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1075)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:383)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:362)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.detectHandlers(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:82)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:58)
 org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:119)
 org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:72)
 org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:73)
 org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:106)
 org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:85)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
 javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)


root cause 

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRegistrationService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.persistent.eap.dao.UserRegistrationDetailsDao com.persistent.eap.service.impl.UserRegistrationServiceImpl.userRegistrationDetailsDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRegistrationDetailsDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0
 org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:844)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:786)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1075)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:383)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:362)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.detectHandlers(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:82)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:58)
 org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:119)
 org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:72)
 org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:73)
 org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:106)
 org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:85)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
 javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)


root cause 

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.persistent.eap.dao.UserRegistrationDetailsDao com.persistent.eap.service.impl.UserRegistrationServiceImpl.userRegistrationDetailsDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRegistrationDetailsDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0
 org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
```

My dispatcher-servlet.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:spring-configured />
    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"/>
    <context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="on"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
    <bean class="com.persistent.eap.validators.UserRegistrationValidator" />
    <bean id="userRegistrationService" class="com.persistent.eap.service.impl.UserRegistrationServiceImpl" />

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.persistent.eap.controllers" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.persistent.eap.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.persistent.eap.dao" />
</beans>

           .....
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0
```

Do you define a EntityManagerFactory implementation in your spring config?

Comment: I had placed it by mistake in my applicationContext.Thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 0):

First, do the following:

```
private ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSoure;

@Autowired
public void setMessageSource(ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSoure) {
    this.messageSoure = messageSoure;
}
```

Then check in configration xml for bean definition.